# how to get text within the open and closed div tags using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Below is the div tag in my application:

```
<div id="templateDetailsCreatedDate" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 templateDetailsCreatedDate detailsSubContainers">Created Date :2015-10-30 09:23:46</div>
```

I want to get text the Created Date: `2015-10-30 09:23:46`. I tried using following selenium code it returned null value:

```
element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='templateDetailsCreatedDate']")).getText();

system.out.println(+element);

output: null
```

Comment: <div id="templateDetailsCreatedDate" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 templateDetailsCreatedDate detailsSubContainers">Created Date :2015-10-30 09:23:46</div>

Comment: Why are you printing `+element` instead of just `element`?

Comment: It's a spell mistake @ mattia... In my eclipse I used the correct statement system.out.println(element); I got the same output null

Comment: Please fix your code to what you are actually using and provide more details. Clearly something else is going on in the page that is causing this simple statement to not work. Are there IFRAMEs or ???

Comment: Need help with the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675998/extract-data-from-div-tags-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

I would use By.id directly:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id("templateDetailsCreatedDate")).getText();
system.out.println(element);
```

Comment: I tried using alternatives By.id, By.css... Still the output null

It seems problem is in identifying text in div tag.... Can you look at this problem once again

Thanks